# cypress onRequest handler fails if any cy. method used inside

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

Basically, my task is next: when my app triggers outgoing xhr request I want to make some assertions on the request payload, and continue with other assertions, once the request is fulfilled.
So what i did is used `onRequest` option on `cy.route` method which lets you have access to outgoing xhr request. My initial code looked like this:

```
cy.server();
cy.route({
  method:'POST',
  url:'/api/v3/table-metas/**',
  onRequest(xhr) {
    console.log('==========BEFORE========');
    cy.wrap(xhr).
    its('request').
    its('body').
    its('embedded').
    should('to.deep.equal',
      [
        {
          "attributes": {
            "name": "Test Name"
          },
          "type": "test_type"
        }
      ]
    ).debug();
    console.log('=============AFTER===========');
 }
}).as('getTableMetas');
```

But this code make my app think that request failed, and in cypress log it was showing me that request was pending until it failed with timeout.
Then I decided to remove my assertion, and everything works fine!:

```
cy.server();
cy.route({
  method:'POST',
  url:'/api/v3/table-metas/**',
  onRequest(xhr) {
    console.log('==========BEFORE========');
    console.log('=============AFTER===========');
 }
}).as('getTableMetas');
```

Thus, I decided that the problem is in my assertion code, and did some testing with other `cy` methods, but it seems that any `cy.` method leads to exactly the same failure:

```
cy.server();
cy.route({
  method:'POST',
  url:'/api/v3/table-metas/**',
  onRequest(xhr) {
    console.log('==========BEFORE========');
    cy.log('AAAAAAAAAAAA');
    console.log('=============AFTER===========');
 }
}).as('getTableMetas');
```

Here is the screenshot of cypress log for the last part of code:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?
If it is designed behavior of cypress, then how am I supposed to assert outgoing request body?

Would be grateful for any kind of help

Answer (score 1):

> When given an alias argument:
>
> cy.wait() yields an object containing the HTTP request and response    properties of the XHR. [Source](http://When%20given%20an%20alias%20argument:%20%20cy.wait()%20yields%20an%20object%20containing%20the%20HTTP%20request%20and%20response%20properties%20of%20the%20XHR.)

A property getter can be chained to the yielded object from calling the waits method. *e.g.*

```
it('verifies request body', () => {
  cy.server();
  cy.route({
    method:'POST',
    url:'/api/v3/table-metas/**',
    onRequest(xhr) {
      console.log('==========BEFORE========');
      console.log('=============AFTER===========');
   }
  }).as('getTableMetas');
  
  // do some action that makes a request to the intercepted request

  cy.waits('@getTableMetas')
    .its('request.body.embedded')
    .should('to.deep.equal', [
      {
        "attributes": {
          "name": "Test Name"
        },
        "type": "test_type"
      }
    ]).debug();
});
```

**Update**:

`onRequest` is executed as a callback, calling `cy.wraps` creates a promise during the execution that is never resolved.

I suggest to use normal `chai` assertions in `onRequest` callback instead as they are synchronous.

```
expect(xhr.request.body.embedded).to.deep.equal([
        {
          "attributes": {
            "name": "Test Name"
          },
          "type": "test_type"
        }
      ])
```

Comment: I have tried with `done()`
and this code still fails:
`onRequest(xhr) { cy.log('AAAAA'); done(); }`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just read this docs and my previous answer was on a wrong assumption. I discovered that [all Cypress commands are asynchronous](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Commands-Are-Asynchronous) so `done` doesn't change anything. You want to do your assert on the object yielded from waits.

Comment: Yes, your last code would work. But my initial idea was to test request body regardless of the xhr request result (whether it fails or succeed), thus I decided to use `onRequest` callback, and it did not work out as I expected. Thus at this point, I would like to figure out why my approach did not work. Maybe my approach is completely incorrect (then I would like to know why), or maybe it's fine, but I am missing something really small.
But anyway, thanks for your help and time!

Comment: Thank for your feedback. I suspect that is happening because cypress commands are promise like and calling a promise inside of the onRequest callback isn't supported.